# Is it possible to add jQuery UI theme (Combobox, button) to dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ex: A dynamic select box or a button (from ajax response) when inserted into a page should render in jQuery UI ComboBox style or jQuery UI Button style.

```
$.get("someurl", function(html){
  $("p").append(html); 
 // at this point the selectbox & button should be rendered as 
 // jQuery UI combobox & jQuery UI Button 
}
```

**Edited**

response html contains form with list of textfield, selectbox & button

```
<select name="scope" >
 <option value="in">in</option>
 <option value="out">out</option>
</select>

<div class="buttonContainer">
 <button name="save">Save</button>
 <button name="cancel">Cancel</button>               
</div>
```

After the html is appended I want to style select box using $("select").combobox(). In my main page (js file) I have already added the below line in document ready method.

```
 $("select").combobox() 
 $("button").button()
```

Like jQuery has **.on()** to attach event handler function to dynamic elements. In the same way is it possible to add UI theme (combobox, button) to dynamic elements ?

**Updated:**

I guess triggering an event when ever the page html is loaded (by ajax). 
http://jsfiddle.net/ECJ8N/

```
$("body").bind( "uirender", function() {
    $("select").combobox(); 
    $("button").button() ;           
});
```

and the ajax response would do

```
$.get("someurl", function(html){
  $("p").append(html).trigger("uirender");
}
```

Isn't there a better approach than this ?

Comment: Show some example of what html you are receiving. and if possible how the combobox/button look like as well.